# os.chdir() gives error when calling via c++

Tags: python, c++, python-embedding

I've wrote this code to change the working directory of the python to the c++ directory:

```
Py_Initialize();

// Get the c++ working directory
QString working_directory = QFileInfo(".").absolutePath();
qDebug() << "C++ wd: " << working_directory;

PyRun_SimpleString("import os");

// Import the os module
PyObject* pyOSModule = PyImport_ImportModule("os");
// Convert the std::string to c string
const char * wdCString = working_directory.toStdString().c_str();
// Create python working directory string
PyObject* pyWd = PyUnicode_FromString(wdCString);
// The chdir function of the os module
PyObject* pyChdirFunction = PyObject_GetAttrString(pyOSModule,(char*)"chdir");

// Call the chdir method with the working directory as argument
PyObject_CallFunction(pyChdirFunction, "s", pyWd);
PyRun_SimpleString("print('Python wd: ' + os.getcwd())");
```

The output is:

```
C++ wd:  "Q:/Q/UVC Luftreinigungsanlage/System/Air Purification Management System"
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '\x01'
```

The strange thing is that with normal python shell "Q:/Q/UVC Luftreinigungsanlage/System/Air Purification Management System" is a valid string for os.chdir() and this works, but I see no difference to this called with the Python.h library.

Comment: The result of `working_directory.toStdString()` is a temporary, whose `c_str()` value vanished with it. Try a different method of getting your C-style string.

Comment: On Linux consider using [getcwd(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getcwd.2.html) from your C++ code. See also the  [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/) library

Comment: With [Qt](https://qt.io/) you could use [QDir::current](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#current)

Answer (score 2):

`wdCString` is a dangling pointer - `working_directory.toStdString()` is a temporary object whose lifetime has ended at the next line.

You can either extend its lifetime,

```
const std::string& wd = working_directory.toStdString();
const char * wdCString = wd.c_str();
```

or pass the pointer directly,

```
PyObject* pyWd = PyUnicode_FromString(working_directory.toStdString().c_str());
```

Comment: I changed it but it still gives me the error. Also i can turn pyWd back to QString and print it out and it's still the expected path, so it obviously not has been destroyed.

Comment: @532465747 You can't determine that an object is valid through inspection. Undefined behaviour is nasty.

Comment: ok but sadly it still not works anyway, gives the same error